# Shopify HMAC parameter verification failing in Python

Tags: python, shopify, hmac

I'm having some trouble verifying the HMAC parameter coming from Shopify. The code I'm using per the [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#verification) is returning an incorrect result.

Here's my annotated code:

```
import urllib
import hmac
import hashlib

qs = "hmac=96d0a58213b6aa5ca5ef6295023a90694cf21655cf301975978a9aa30e2d3e48&locale=en&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=myshopname.myshopify.com&timestamp=1520883022"
```

**Parse the querystring**

```
params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(qs)
```

**Extract the hmac value**

```
value = params['hmac'][0]
```

**Remove parameters from the querystring per documentation**

```
del params['hmac']
del params['signature']
```

**Recombine the parameters**

```
new_qs = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
```

**Calculate the digest**

```
h = hmac.new(SECRET.encode("utf8"), msg=new_qs.encode("utf8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
```

**Returns `False`!**

```
hmac.compare_digest(h.hexdigest(), value)
```

That last step should, ostensibly, return true. Every step followed here is outlined as commented in the Shopify docs.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Oops, that would be a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At some point, recently, Shopify started including the `protocol` parameter in the querystring payload. This itself wouldn't be a problem, *except* for the fact that Shopify doesn't document that `:` and `/` are not to be URL-encoded when checking the signature. This is unexpected, given that they themselves *do* URL-encode these characters in the query string that is provided.

To fix the issue, provide the `safe` parameter to `urllib.parse.urlencode` with the value `:/` (fitting, right?). The full working code looks like this:

```
params = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(qs)
cleaned_params = []
hmac_value = dict(params)['hmac']

# Sort parameters
for (k, v) in sorted(params):
    if k in ['hmac', 'signature']:
        continue

    cleaned_params.append((k, v))

new_qs = urllib.parse.urlencode(cleaned_params, safe=":/")
secret = SECRET.encode("utf8")
h = hmac.new(secret, msg=new_qs.encode("utf8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha256)

# Compare digests
hmac.compare_digest(h.hexdigest(), hmac_value)
```

Hope this is helpful for others running into this issue!

Comment: My pleasure, @SamCreamer!

Comment: Probably too late, but anybody knows where (and what) is the "SECRET"? I tried with the "API Secret Key", but does not validate (returns False)...

Comment: @lowercase00 That should be it; at least that's what I have in my codebase.

Comment: @DanLoewenherz The "value" in last line of code should be "hmac_value"

Answer (score 1):

```
import hmac
import hashlib


...

# Inside your view in Django's views.py
params = request.GET.dict()
#

myhmac = params.pop('hmac')
params['state'] = int(params['state'])
line = '&'.join([
    '%s=%s' % (key, value)
    for key, value in sorted(params.items())
])
print(line)
h = hmac.new(
    key=SHARED_SECRET.encode('utf-8'),
    msg=line.encode('utf-8'),
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
)

# Cinderella ?
print(hmac.compare_digest(h.hexdigest(), myhmac))
```